# AWS Linux - Where is MySQL cnf file to edit packet size?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm getting `MySQL server has gone away` errors. I don't quite know why it's happening but after doing some research the most oft-recommended answers involve editing the cnf file to increase packet size and other settings.

Problem is I cannot locate this file. Where would it be?

I find a `my.cnf` file under `/etc` but all it contains is the following:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change max allowed packet size by setting up the variable in config.

Just add `max_allowed_packet=500M` in the `[mysqld]` section.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

max_allowed_packet=500M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

After updating the config you need to restart MySQL services to take effect.

**Note: Maximum size of variable is 1024 MB.**

Comment: I've done this and reset successfully, but when I then check the variable again in Workbench it tells me that the maximum hasn't changed...